# Image files no longer appear in production how to fix the problem

Tags: django, heroku

Before anyone can tell me how to put the other question solved? Hello local site works well, but in Heroku the picture is not displayed anymore

In production the static files are at the same level as the folder of the images according to the logging that's what breaks the problem thank you for your help.
the file upload images is img_url

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Heroku has an ephemeral filesystem. Each running dyno is an independent container. So if you store a file on disk, it will be lost (and not recoverable) once the dyno restarts (which happens whenever the app is deployed, or once every 24 hours).

You need to store your files on a dedicated storage system, such as Amazon S3.
See https://help.heroku.com/K1PPS2WM/why-are-my-file-uploads-missing-deleted

Comment: So we cannot use ImageField in Heroku? And if so, if I deploy it to a server (e.g. AWS) the images come back or you still have to use URLField and not ImageField. By your experience

Comment: You can definitely use an image field to do uploads. But you'll have to either do the upload directly to S3, or upload to your server and call S3 in the backend instead of saving on disk.

Comment: Yes, I understood that with the document that you provided me and thank you, but if I do not configure and I host my website in AWS (i.e. server). It works or the configuration step is required.